# Windows server 2012 R2 RDP auto login users are disconnected

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

as the title says I was wondering if it is possible to auto login RDP users when the server starts up as disconnected.

I have a file server at home running many different applications but my house is prone to power failure so the server gets restarted at least once a week.

The server has 2 RDP accounts for me and my brother, we have different programs running (I have a few virtual machines, my brother has cloud cloud storage etc etc)

The problem is when the server does restart none of the programs will run until we log into our accounts on the server using RDP.

If it is possible I would like the server to automatically login both the RDP accounts in a disconnected state.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you should take a look and see if these application(s) can be made to be run a service.

Comment: Is it 2012R2 or 2008R2?  Your tags conflict.   Why do you have to login restart your VMs?   What hypervisor are you using?  Use Hyper-V, and VMs can be easily set to auto-start.

Comment: Oh, sorry its 2012 R2, I didn't read the tag properly. And no some of the programs can't be made into a service. I'm also using Virtualbox instead of Hyper-V.